# Is language L2 Context free or not?

Tags: context-free-grammar

How this language is Context free?

$\mathcal{L2}=\{a^ib^jc^i \;|\;i,j\geq 1\}$
Please explain me.

Answer (score 7):

$$S\to a A c$$
$$A\to a A c$$
$$A\to bB$$
$$B\to bB$$
$$B\to \epsilon$$

Comment: Is this language CFL?

Comment: @sudhir:  The answer contains a context-free grammar which generates your language, so yes.